Can't find dropdown to add file as link in Visual Studio
I am trying to reuse a .cc and .h files from one project to the other under the same solution in Visual Studio. I found this link, which shows a dropdown option I should click and select "Add as Link". However, I can not find such option.

I am using
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.7.6

